# The website should open only for our proxy addres

Tags: php, .htaccess

Currently, I am developing an web application.But the thing is we are in the Proxy
Network provided by our college.My question is my website should open only for our college proxy network.If the traffic comes from open network It should be redirected.Application developed in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a .htaccess file in your root domain and paste the code below

```
 order allow,deny
 deny from All
 allow from your_ip_address
```

Comment: Thanks man ,thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

The proxy address can be fetched from the server variable. In our campus, the proxy address could be found in

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
```

You can also try checking the variable

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

Comment: Thanks man ,thanks for helping